# How to create a web service proxy? Can we generate @Endpoints?

Tags: java, web-services, spring, proxy, jaxb

I'm working on a web-service-proxy with auditing (later on with caching = creating own responses) and I need to generate @Endpoints (such that will just forward i.e. call a remote web service or dummy atleast). Marshaling/unmarshaling seems neccessary for the proxy will add "something" to the request...

We are to use spring-ws and JAXB. Got all XSDs and static WSDLs of the proxied web service.

Any hints around? Anyone doing something similar? How are you doing it?

Is there a simple way how to achieve this using spring or spring-integration?

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be possible using both Spring WS and Spring Integration:

With Spring WS, you can create a proxy class for your remote WS, wrapping around a [org.springframework.ws.client.core.WebServiceTemplate](http://static.springsource.org/spring-ws/sites/2.0/apidocs/org/springframework/ws/client/core/WebServiceTemplate.html) to talk to the WS - which has API's to take care of marshalling the request to xml and unmarshalling the response.

With Spring Integration, you can use an [outbound Webservices gateway](http://static.springsource.org/spring-integration/reference/htmlsingle/#webservices-namespace) , but you will need to front it with a messaging gateway, which will act as your proxy, along these lines:

```
<int:gateway id="wsproxy"  service-interface="..ProxyInterface" default-request-channel="requestChannel" default-reply-channel="replyChannel"/>

<int-ws:outbound-gateway id="wsGateway" request-channel="requestChannel" uri="http://serviceURL" marshaller="someMarshaller" unmarshaller="someUnmarshaller"/>
```

However, I would recommend the first approach of using the WebserviceTemplate, as you do not have a very complex integration need here.

Answer (score 0):

Today I can tell how we proceeded without spring-integration. We found two different ways how to generate @Endpoint class.

**1)** Using **XSLT** and **Freemarker** we generated the endpoint class source in ***pre-compile*** phase. XSLT transformation walked thru all WSDL files to create one summary file which was then used to generate the source.

**2)** Using **Javassist** we copied the template class, then generated methods regarding content of **JAXB2Marshaller** instance and finally instantiated object using **FactoryBean**, all at server ***start-up***.

Problem here we met was set of XSD files written in form that caused the root objects were generated without @XmlRootAnnotation. Javassist version we had internally works with Java 1.4 (no generics) so we used global customization file for XJC and forced @XmlRootAnnotation on root objects.

Both solutions have their pros and cons but both are simpler then using ESB.